# How to turn js functions from asynchronious calling to callback calling

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make my first Google Chrome extension. This extension must intercept requests to mysite.com and redirect user to one of the site mirrors (e.g. mymirror.com). URL of actual mirror extension getting from my API-server (e.g. api.service.com) for first intercepted request and stores it to cookies for next requests.

**manifest.json**:

```
{
    "name": "InterceptMySite",
    "version": "0.1",
    "description": "My first Chrome extension",
    "permissions": ["webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "cookies",
                    "*://mysite.com/*", "*://api.service.com/*"],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },

    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

**background.js**:

```
function setMirrorUrl(callback) {
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open('GET', 'http://api.service.com', false); // sync request
        req.send(null);
        req.onload = function() {
            callback(this.getResponseHeader('Mirror-Url'));
        }
    }
    function getMirrorUrl(callback) {
        chrome.cookies.get({url:'http://api.service.com',name:'mirror_url'}, function(cookie) {
            if ( ! cookie)
                return setMirrorUrl(callback);
            else
                return callback(cookie.value);
        });
    }
    chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
        function(info) {
            if(info.url.indexOf('api.service.com') != -1)
                return {cancel:false};

            getMirrorUrl(function(mirror_url){

                return {redirectUrl: info.url.replace(/mysite.com/i, mirror_url)};

            });

        },
        // filters
        {
            urls: [
                "*://mysite.com/*",
                "*://api.service.com/*"
            ]
        },
        // extraInfoSpec
        ["blocking"]
    );
```

All works fine **except** one thing: **getMirrorUrl()** called asynchronously. So, **onBeforeRequest** event listener completed before getMirrorUrl() finished. Plus, getMirrorUrl somehow must to pass result to the onBeforeRequest listener.

I know it must be rewritten to callback-style, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing **is** callback-style! you ask for a cookie and get it asynchronously with your callback.

You could do the API call synchronously (although that would be ugly), but the cookie "get" operation has to be asynchronous. So I think you'll need to preload the mirror URLs beforehand (for example as soon as the page is loaded), then when a link is clicked you retrieve the corresponding URL.

Another way I'd try would be to set the `redirectUrl` to the current page, load the mirror URL asynchronously and trigger a page change as soon as it is loaded (I am not sure, I've never done that from the extension API).